# Is there a way to nest a survival plot with a Magnified y scale in its original scale plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to mimic the style of survival plot in the NEW ENGLAND JOURNAL OF MEDICINE. It often nests a survival plot with a Magnified y scale in its original scale plot. Just like this:

[image]

I can use survival and survminer R package to draw a survival plot with no. of at-risk easily. However, I've no idea to nest a survival plot with a Magnified y scale.

Here is the code I've tried.

```
library("survival")
library("survminer")
library("ggplot2")
fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ sex, data = lung)

p1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, pval = TRUE, fun = "pct",
                 risk.table = TRUE, size = 1,
                 tables.theme = theme_cleantable())
p2 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, pval = TRUE, fun = "pct", ylim=c(50, 100))

library(grid)
vp <- viewport(width =0.6, height = 0.6, x = 1,y = 1)
p1
print(p2,vp = vp)
```

However, it seems that the viewport function doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case did not provide a suitable example because your data spanning from 100 to 0%. However herein a working code:

```
library("survival")
library("survminer")
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")

fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ sex, data = lung)

p1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, pval = TRUE, fun = "pct",
                 risk.table = TRUE, size = 1,
                 legend = "none",
                 palette = c("#377eb8", "#e41a1c"),
                 tables.theme = theme_cleantable())

p2 <- p1$plot + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(50, 100)) + theme(legend.position = "none") + labs(x="", y="")

vp <- viewport(width = 0.3, height = 0.3, x = 1, y = 0.7, just = c("right","bottom"))

full <- function() {
  print(p1)
  theme_set(theme_classic())
  print(p2, vp = vp)
}

full()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the case is not suitable.  I just want to use this case to draw a nested graph.

Comment: Great! If it solve your question you should accept the answer and upvote! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I know the reason now. We have to abstract the ggplot object  out from ggsurvplot.